# Изменить стиль выделения заголовка столбца DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, datagridview

На скриншотах: первая строка ListView, вторая строка DataGridView.

Когда нажимаешь на заголовок ListView, он выделяется и перестает. Когда ходишь по DataGridView выделение заголовка остается. И я имею ввиду не цвет, а то что происходит "утопление" ячейки выделенного столбца. Можно от этого уйти? Либо убрать выделение шапки, либо убрать "утопление" при активном выделении.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> И я имею ввиду не цвет, а то что происходит "утопление" ячейки выделенного столбца.

Это не просто утопление, это сортировка строк таблицы по заданному столбцу. Посмотрите на треугольник сбоку. Если щелкните еще раз, то порядок сортировки изменится и треугольник перевернется.

[image: Треугольник в заголовке столбца]

> Можно от этого уйти? Либо убрать выделение шапки, либо убрать "утопление" при активном выделении.

Можно сделать столбец несортируемым, для этого нужно для столбца `DataGridView` установить свойству [`SortMode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.sortmode?view=netframework-4.8) значение `NotSortable`.

Вот пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();

        var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill } ;
        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "Сортируемый"
        });
        grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "Несортируемый",
            SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        });
        grid.Rows.Add(new[] { "Раз", "Два" });
        grid.Rows.Add(new[] { "Три", "Четыре" });
        grid.Rows.Add(new[] { "Пять", "Шесть" });

        var form = new Form
        {
            ClientSize = new Size(300, 200)
        };
        form.Controls.Add(grid);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

А вот результат:

[image: Сортируемый и несортируемый столбцы]

Если нужно, чтобы при наведении столбец выделялся, но при этом не сортировался, то можно установить `SortMode = Programmatic` и при этом не обрабатывать событие [`SortCompare`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare?view=netframework-4.8).

Код:

```
grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        {
            HeaderText = "Несортируемый",
            SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
        });
```

Пример:

[image: Выделение при наведении без сортировки]

Если же нужно отключить вообще любое выделение в столбцах, то можно установить свойство `DataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles` в `false`. Тогда сортировка сохранится, но столбцы выделяться не будут.

Если в примере выше изменить инициализацию таблицы на:

```
var grid = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false };
```

, то получится следующее:

[image: Сортировка без выделения]